# get value using bind() javascript

Tags: javascript

```
test = {
    var1: 25,
    func1: function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(this.var1);
        }, 100);
    }
}
bar.func1();
```

how to get the value in func1 using bind() method. It can be done using arrow function but I want to achieve it using bind() method.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `.bind(this)`.

```js
test = {
    var1: 25,
    func1: function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(this.var1);
        }.bind(this), 100);
    }
}
test.func1();
```